# Capitalize first letter of a part of an href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following kind of link:

http://myexampple.com/gallery/overview/portrait#

Where the word `portrait` changes, it is dynamic depending on custom post. I need to capitalize the first letter of it so I get:

http://myexampple.com/gallery/overview/Portrait#

any idea how to do it?

Comment: Can you explain why would you need to capitalize it?

Comment: I'm not sure it's actually going to make a difference. As long as you don't reference the .html, capilization doesn't matter I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string replace with a regular expression

```
var str = "http://myexampple.com/gallery/overview/portrait#"
var updated = str.replace(/(\/.)([^\/]+[#$])/, function(full, f, s){ return f.toUpperCase() + s;});
```

Comment: the word overview will always change so I can't put the str that way... any idea?

Comment: The code does not reference overview... You set str to whatever the string is you are changing!

Answer (score 0):

you can define a function called replaceAt (index , with )

I suggest :

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}
```

and now you can call it like this :

```
var link = $("link-id").text() ;
var index = link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 ;
link = link.replaceAt (index , index.toUpperCase() ) ;
$("link-id").html(link) ;
```